# SQL query to retrieve discrepancies in punch order

Tags: sql

Consider the table below.

The rule is - an employee cannot take a break (needs to clock out) from job num 1 before clocking in to job num 2. In this case the employee "A" was supposed to clock OUT instead of BREAK on jobnum 1 because he later clocked in to JobNum#2

Is it possible to write a query to find this in plain SQL?

[image: table]

Comment: if your engine supports LEAD and LAG then you can write a nice one..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is to check if next record is proper one. To find next record one has to find first punchtime after current for same employee. Once this information is retrieved one can isolate record itself and check fields of interest, specifically is jobnum the same and [optionally] is punch_type 'IN'. If it is not, not exists evaluates to true and record is output.

```
select *
from @punch p
-- Isolate breaks only
where p.punch_type = 'BREAK'
-- The ones having no proper entry
and not exists
(
    select null
    -- The same table
    from @punch a
    where a.emplid = p.emplid
      and a.jobnum = p.jobnum
    -- Next record has punchtime from subquery
      and a.punchtime = (select min (n.punchtime) 
                           from @punch n 
                          where n.emplid = p.emplid 
                            and n.punchtime > p.punchtime
                        )
    -- Optionally you might force next record to be 'IN'
      and a.punch_type = 'IN'
)
```

Replace @punch with your table name. `--` is comment in Sql Server; if you are not using this database, remove this lines. It is a good idea to tag your database and version as there are probably faster/better ways to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the SQL

```
    select * from employees e1 cross join employees e2 where e1.JOBNUM = (e2.JOBNUM + 1) 
    and e1.PUNCH_TYPE = 'BREAK' and e2.PUNCH_TYPE = 'IN'
    and e1.PUNCHTIME < e2.PUNCHTIME
            and e1.EMPLID = e2.EMPLID
```

Comment: The query returns true even for valid rows if someone has IN- BREAK- IN- BREAK-IN-OUT in JOB1  AND IN-OUT in JOB2 . Any ideas?